# SELECT inside JSON structure return empty

Tags: python, sql, json, azure

Using Azure Cosmos DB with the Python SDK, I'm trying to select a value inside a JSON file structured like this:

```
{
"id": "40",
"data": [
    {
        "x": "0.0959",
        "y": "-0.1303",
        "z": "0.0202"
    }
    ]
}
```

My query works with getting all three values `x, y, z` inside `data` but when I try to select a single value with `data.x` it returns an empty list. My query looks like this:

```
Select f.data, f.id from file as f where f.id = "40"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in normal dictionary it would need `f["data"][0]["x"]` - so there is `[0]` - maybe it makes problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` field type seems as an `Array`, so below query has worked for me with your data,

```
Select f.data[0].x, f.data[0].y, f.data[0].z from file as f where f.id = '40'
```

[image]

Comment: @sbjartmar, were you able to get this query working?

Comment: Yes worked like a charm, forgot to comment. Thank you very much!